# how to split data not normally distributed into some samples that should be normally distributed

Tags: python, distribution

when I plot my data (vector of 1000 elements or more) I get something not normally distributed.

[image]

however I believe that I can divide the data into smaller sets which are normally distributed. I am not sure how I can do it in python  or what the fitting criteria should be!

Any Advice please?

Comment: Please provide a minimal code

Comment: how do you generate your data? Why would you expect them to be normally distributed?

Comment: looks like a kernel density estimation problem, you could use `gaussian_kde` from `scipy` or `KernelDensity` from `sklearn`. See https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/ for a comparison... may be outdated though

Comment: Depends on your data/process, if you can do that (not all real life processes follow pure Gaussian response). Looks like there is half-normal and normal distributions combined in the results and divider is in -40 mark.

Comment: KDE problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation